# Issue in displaying activity as an dialog

Tags: android

I have an activity class. For this Activity class, I have an XML layout. I want to display this activity class as a dialog, So to do so in the manifest I do the following change.

```
 <activity
    android:name=".AlarmDialogActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">            
 </activity>
```

When I run my app the activity class display as dialog, But the width of the is compressed, it does not take the full screen of the device. Why does this happen? Can anyone help me to solve this out?

**Code for xml layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_alarm_dialog"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#E0D5B1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_title_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/dialog_title_text"
            android:textColor="#e89192"
            android:textSize="18dp" >
        </TextView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/alarm_list_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:listSelector="#00000000" >
        </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_control_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_dismiss"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_dismiss_text"
            android:textColor="#121212"
            android:textSize="18dp" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Screenshot of the dialog**

[image]

Comment: Did u tried doing what i posted??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_title_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/dialog_title_text"
    android:textColor="#e89192"
    android:textSize="18dp" >
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your xml layout file by:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="xxxxxxxx"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#121212"
            android:textSize="18dp"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        android:textColor="#e89192"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Add whatever style you want to add to layout.

Add below line before setcontentview of activity:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

and this in manifest file under your activity:

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the activity class file:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.copyFrom(dialogPost.getWindow().getAttributes());                      
lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
dialogPost.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);  
dialogPost.show();
```

Where `dialogPost` is a `DialogBox`. You can change your view with `dialogPost`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:layout_width="fill_parent` in your TextView. Its worked for me.